How can I put routes working in production on Hostinger?

I'm currently facing an issue with routing when transitioning from localhost to the server on Hostinger, and I was hoping you could help me out.
Basically, when I'm on localhost/galmi/contactos, everything works fine. However, when I deploy it to production (galmi.pt) on Hostinger, only the homepage works initially. Once I click on any route, like "contactos", it redirects to galmi.pt/galmi/contactos and I get an error message like:

"Oops, looks like the page is lost. This is not a fault, just an accident that was not intentional."

I also tried adjusting the route to be galmi.pt/contactos, but it still doesn't work.
I would greatly appreciate your help in resolving this issue. Thank you!
<?php
// Iniciar a sessão para proteger contra CSRF
session_start();

// Gerar token de CSRF se não existir
if (empty($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $_SESSION['token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
}

// Importações
require_once("requisitos.php");

// Definir URL base dinamicamente
$url_base = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/galmi/';

// Obter a URL da requisição
$rotas = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$rotas = str_replace("/galmi/", "", $rotas); // Ajuste para a pasta do projeto
$rotas = explode("/", $rotas);

// Verifica se há parâmetros GET na URL
if (strpos($rotas[count($rotas) - 1], "?") !== false) {
    $parametros = str_replace("?", "", $rotas[count($rotas) - 1]);
    $parametros = explode("&", $parametros);

    foreach ($parametros as $p) {
        $p = explode("=", $p);
        $_GET[$p[0]] = filter_var($p[1] ?? '', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $rotas[count($rotas) - 1] = explode("?", $rotas[count($rotas) - 1])[0];
    }
}

// Redirecionar URLs que terminam com barra para sem barra
if (substr($rotas[0], -1) == "/") {
    header("Location: " . rtrim($url_base . implode("/", $rotas), "/"));
    exit();
}

// Roteamento das páginas
switch ($rotas[0]) {
    case "":
    case "inicio":
        require_once("models/inicio.php");
        break;
    case "proprietario":
        require_once("models/proprietario.php");
        break;
    case "sobre-nos":
        require_once("models/sobre_nos.php");
        break;
    case "contactos":
        require_once("models/contactos.php");
        break;
    case "termos-de-servico":
        require_once("models/termos.php");
        break;
    case "politica-de-privacidade":
        require_once("models/politica_privacidade.php");
        break;
    default:
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        require_once("models/404.php");
        break;
}
?>

requisitos.php takes you to config.php which will have this code $url_base = "http://localhost/galmi/"; on hostinger I tried to put this way  $url_base = "https://galmi.pt/"; but the problem is the same. My .htaccess is # Ativar Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On
# Definir o base path se o projeto estiver numa subpasta
RewriteBase /galmi/

# Redirecionar tudo para index.php para processamento de rotas
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]

